# Too many arguments in system() call

Tags: c, arguments

I have a problem with arguments in the `system()` call in C.

#### Code:

```
char macaddr[13];
uint8_t mac[6];
memset(macaddr, '\0', 13);
mac_get_ascii_from_file("/sys/class/net/eth0/address", macaddr);

system("rm /var/tuxbox/config/cxx.bin");
system("wget -P /var/tuxbox/config http://xxxxxxx/xx/cxx_%s.bin\n", macaddr);
```

#### Error message:

> too many arguments to function 'system'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system()` doesn't handle `printf` style arguments. You need to build the command string up first and then pass it to system.

e.g.

```
char cmd[512];
sprintf(cmd, "wget -P /var/tuxbox/config http://xxxxxxx/xx/cxx_%s.bin\n", macaddr);
// or snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "wget...
system(cmd);
```

(note, no error handling etc included.)

Comment: Hello i have got this error

undefined reference to `UNSAFE_SPRINTF_USE_SNPRINTF_INSTEAD'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Have you googled snprintf? It is just a safer version of sprintf that takes the length of the buffer as an argument to prevent buffer overruns.

Comment: yes is have googled snprintf 

all time give me 

error undefined reference to `UNSAFE_SPRINTF_USE_SNPRINTF_INSTEAD

Answer (score 0):

Just Don't write

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

if you write that in the first line or second or third lines